# How can I make secure a video online?

Tags: security, video, streaming

I am working on an online video training website and i want to make secure my videos so that no one can download the videos. Can any one help me how can i restrict video download, i have tried different HTML5 and javascript players but none of these are providing this feature.

Comment: This is not possible. Don't put them on the web if you don't want them downloaded. Every player needs to get your video stream from _somewhere_, so it must be available for download.

Comment: By definition, as they are viewed they are downloaded.  Something tells me, however, there won't be a big demand for pirated copies of your scary amazing training videos.  BRB, torrent for Avatar 2 DVD screener just completed.

Comment: Yep will is right,  and this will always be true.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the video files outside of the web root or inside a restricted directory.  A user logs into the web application normally.  Then you have a server side script that checks the users permissions and opens the file for the user.

Alternatively if there is no login then the player can request a token from the web application.  This token is then used to access the file only once.   This is the best you can do,  of course an attacker can still save the file.  A user will always be able to do this until the end of time,  because thats how the Internet works.

Answer (score 0):

you can create the file name longest enough as permitted by server (applies to photos as well)...cannot be saved even from a smart phone...make sure the file name long enough. Then use this encrypter:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/encrypter.htm

Blend in the new code into your html.

Finally use additional scripting to disable right click (search internet for this free script).

Comment: `Finally use additional scripting to disable right click (search internet for this free script).` YEs but you can still get the link from viewing the HTML source.

Answer (score 0):

Stream the video.. Hide the root from the server there's many ways to do that. Encrypt the file do all the right clicks off when over the stream. And for the end choose a very rare format! A normal user will give up. An advanced user will get it no matter what!